# How to initialize d3.scale.utc() using moment.js

Tags: d3.js, momentjs, utc

My server side model is saving date/time in UTC.
In my front end I am using moment.js to create time objects using the server side data.

However, I am using d3 to plot the data and I am not quite sure how I can initialize `d3.scale.utc()` using my moment object. I need to render the axis scale in UTC time.

Previously, `d3.scale.utc().domain(starDate, endDate)` was working where `startDate` and `endDate` were native JavaScript date objects.

But now that I have refactored the code to use moment.js to handle UTC time and making some of the date and time manipulation functions simplified, I am facing this plotting issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a moment object and you want to feed it to `d3`?  Easiest way is to just use JavaScript epoch times obtained via [valueOf()](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/unix-offset/):

```js
var startDate = moment().subtract(10, 'hours').utc();
var endDate = moment().add(10, 'hours').utc();

var x = d3.time.scale.utc()
  .domain([startDate.valueOf(), endDate.valueOf()])    
  .range([0, 400]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", 410)
    .attr("height", 210)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + 10 + "," + 10+ ")");

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + 0 + ")")
    .call(xAxis)
  .selectAll("text")
    .attr("y", 0)
    .attr("x", 9)
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(90)")
    .style("text-anchor", "start");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.11.1/moment.js"></script>
```